# Anyway to set RMQ Consumer delivery timeout on per-message level?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

We have a use case that holds active jobs in a RabbitMQ job queue.   The Clients, when they are free, pull jobs from this queue.   Pretty normal.   But in our case, we do not ACK the jobs.   We allow them to stay in the Unacked state so if the Client dies, the job goes to a pre-defined DeadLetter queue.   We then have a process that pulls messages from dead-letter, and decides to either requeue message back to original job-queue, or discard.

This has worked well for a long time.    Now, we have upgraded to a newer version of RMQ, and found that we get disconnects with PRECONDITION_FAILED, because the default ack timeout of 30 minutes has expired.

Beyond removing this from the server, does anyone know a way to configure this on a per-message level?

While some might say just ACK the job, and use a handler to return to DEADLETTER if needed.    Well, sorry, that will not work for us.

So, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not at this time. You should configure the default to be greater than the longest expected job duration. Please note that if you are using quorum queues this may cause disk usage growth because the log files can't be compacted while messages are outstanding.

We may make this timeout configurable in a more granular way, so please keep an eye on future RabbitMQ releases for that.